# Subversion post-commit error: Couldn't open rep-cache database

Tags: azure, svn, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, azure-virtual-machine

I have installed Apache2 / Subversion v1.9.3 on an Azure Ubuntu 16.04 instance using the approach described [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51753).

I have configured SSL in `sites-available/[sitename].conf`, and  am able to connect remotely using Firefox and TortoiseSvn.

If I create a repo on the server's local filesystem everything works perfectly - I can import files to the repo using TortoiseSvn without error.

If I replace the repo with one hosted on an Azure Fileservice storage, mounted with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //[].file.core.windows.net/svn /mnt/svn -o vers=3.0,username=[],password=[],dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp,uid=www-data,gid=www-data
```

...Tortoise SVN reports `post commit FS processing had error: Couldn't open rep-cache database`

`/var/log/apache/error.log` contains the following:

```
[Sat May 26 15:12:00.994705 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140074997974784] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 77.144.98.30:55324] Couldn't open rep-cache database
[Sat May 26 15:12:00.994745 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140074997974784] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 77.144.98.30:55324] -Couldn't perform atomic initialization
[Sat May 26 15:12:00.994749 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140074997974784] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 77.144.98.30:55324] -sqlite[S5]: database is locked, executing statement 'CREATE TABLE rep_cache (   hash TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   revision INTEGER NOT NULL,   offset INTEGER NOT NULL,   size INTEGER NOT NULL,   expanded_size INTEGER NOT NULL   ); PRAGMA USER_VERSION = 1; '
[Sat May 26 15:12:02.713630 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140075207550720] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 77.144.98.30:55324] Couldn't open rep-cache database
[Sat May 26 15:12:02.713658 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140075207550720] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 77.144.98.30:55324] -Couldn't perform atomic initialization
[Sat May 26 15:12:02.867911 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140075207550720] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 77.144.98.30:55324] Couldn't open rep-cache database
[Sat May 26 15:12:02.867922 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140075207550720] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client 77.144.98.30:55324] -Couldn't perform atomic initialization
[Sat May 26 15:12:03.801075 2018] [:error] [pid 11577:tid 140075207550720] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): commit of r1 succeeded, but an error occurred after the commit: 'post commit FS processing had error:\nCouldn't open rep-cache database'
```

[This](http://grokbase.com/t/subversion/users/11berssad3/couldnt-open-rep-cache-database-post-commit-fs-processing) question appears to address the same problem, however it is not clear to me whether it's possible to modify the module load order in Apache2 as module configuration is based on the contents of `mods-enabled/*.load`.

The permissions on the files in the repo dir appear to be reasonable...although there are rather a few zero-sized files:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     2 May 26 15:12 current
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    41 May 26 15:08 format
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 10178 May 26 15:08 fsfs.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     5 May 26 15:08 fs-type
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     2 May 26 15:08 min-unpacked-rev
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:11 rep-cache.db
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:12 rep-cache.db-journal
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:08 revprops
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:08 revs
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:08 transactions
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     2 May 26 15:11 txn-current
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:08 txn-current-lock
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:08 txn-protorevs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data    74 May 26 15:08 uuid
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     0 May 26 15:08 write-lock
```

However, if there were a problem with the module load order, I would imagine the the problem would occur whether or not the repo is on a local or mounted file system.

Is this the correct approach for storing subversion repository data in Azure?

Any insight or guidance on how better to diagnose / resolve the problem would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A few more tests suggest that the problem is with the use of the Azure Fileservice for the storage of subversion repository data.

One of the processes in the [setup](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51753) is to create the repo:

```
sudo svnadmin create /path/to/repo
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/repo
sudo chmod -R g+ws /path/to/repo
```

When this is performed on a local (ext4?) drive, the `db` dir looks something like this:

```
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data     2 May 26 18:56 current
-r--rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data    41 May 26 18:54 format
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data 10178 May 26 18:54 fsfs.conf
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data     5 May 26 18:54 fs-type
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data     2 May 26 18:54 min-unpacked-rev
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data  3072 May 26 18:56 rep-cache.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data     0 May 26 18:56 rep-cache.db-journal
drwxrwsr-x 3 www-data www-data  4096 May 26 18:54 revprops
drwxrwsr-x 3 www-data www-data  4096 May 26 18:54 revs
drwxrwsr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 May 26 18:56 transactions
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data     2 May 26 18:56 txn-current
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data     0 May 26 18:54 txn-current-lock
drwxrwsr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 May 26 18:56 txn-protorevs
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data    74 May 26 18:54 uuid
-rw-rwSr-- 1 www-data www-data     0 May 26 18:54 write-lock
```

...which with the s/S flags is different from the contents of the directory on the Azure fileservice (shown in the question). Not being a Linux expert, I assume that these are [features not supported by the Azure file service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/features-not-supported-by-the-azure-file-service).

My solution is thus to [create and attach a data disk to the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal), and then [partition, format and mount](https://chrismckee.co.uk/creating-mounting-new-drives-in-ubuntu-azure/) the disk. The repo can then be created as above, and everything works as it should.

Answer (score -1):

It's a limitation of sqlite DB. As the size of the repo grows you see this. I fixed it by dividing my svn repo to smaller chunks.

Comment: Not sure about this as we get this error on tiny repos too after migration.